# Issue after upgrading from angular 2 to 4

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting following error when updated my app from angular 2 to angular 4

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Only
>   initialized variables and constants can be referenced because the
>   value of this variable is needed by the template compiler (position
>   663:22 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol Component in
>   D:/mdp/mdp-internaltools-app/node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata/directives.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol ProcessingComponent in
>   D:/mdp/mdp-internaltools-app/src/app/processing-component/processing-component.component.ts,
>   resolving symbol ProcessingComponent in
>   D:/mdp/mdp-internaltools-app/src/app/processing-component/processing-component.component.ts
>
> ```
> ERROR in ./src/index.ts
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory' in
> ```
>
> 'D:\mdp\mdp-internaltools-app\src'
>       @ ./src/index.ts 3:0-75
>       @ multi ./src/index

I am unable to identify the error since a long time, does anyone else also got the same error.

**processing-component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';

@Component({
    selector: 'mdp-processing',
    template: require('./processing-component.component.html')
})
export class ProcessingComponent {

}
```

**processing.component.html**

```
 <!-- Processing Tab Navigation -->
    <mdp-processing-navbar></mdp-processing-navbar>

    <!-- Processing Tab Main section/tabs -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: cam you show the process component

Comment: Rahul Singh I've updated the post

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need `require` in your template.

Second, make sure you have all proper versions of all project dependencies. For me, the simplest way to upgrade from A2 to A4 was with Angular CLI. Generate a new project, say Hello-CLI. Then copy dependencies and devDependencies sections from Hello-CLI package.json into the package.json of your A2 project and then run npm install.

Third, make sure that your bootstrap code (main.ts) is located in a separate file from your app module.